# How to translate breadcrumbs on a views page?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, breadcrumbs

I am facing problem regarding translation of Views title.
[image]
breadcrumbs is not translated. 
I have used view on this page. Its title is Latest News.
Could anyone please help?

Translate interface

[image]

Comment: Is that a taxonomy view? Have you tried to translate it on `admin/config/regional/translate`?

Comment: I have tried translating at admin/config/regional/translate
I have added image please could you check it. There is Japanese text but its not being translated. Could you please help

Comment: So what happens when you click on `edit` and add an English string then?

Comment: Its not giving provision for English.
It is displaying :

Original text
Latest News


Context
blog:page_3:title 


Japanese
(Japanese text)

I have provided Japanese text.

Comment: I have added image. Please could you check it.

Comment: Then what is your default language under `admin/config/regional/language`? And in what language are you currently working in? From your very first screenshot it looks as if you are on the Japanese site since nihongo is highlighted, are you?

Comment: Japanese is my default Language. I am working in English language right now.

Comment: Can you add your last comment into your question please?

Comment: Japanese is my default Language. I am working in English language right now.